# how to extract substring using regular expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

For instance, I have a table saves a bunch of URLs.

```
like http://...?action_press=1&pid=56523
```

I want to get all the id of variable pid.
I want to write something like `"pid=(\d+)"` to extract all these ID out.

I don't want to use locate(), because sometimes the url may looks like

```
?pid=56523&action_press=1
```

Is it possible to use regular expression to realize it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_column, 'pid=', -1), '&', 1)
FROM
    tbl
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/506b7/1/0)

Comment: this will also match an argument where 'pid' is a suffix of the name. eg it will match 'xyzpid='.